# SSRS - How to Get Filter Data to appear in Reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

This is a simple question for someone with SSRS background. I am bit of a beginner to it and wondering when a report is generated, how do you get the drop down headers to appear on the report.

Say for example you got a column with username. Then you want to just select one username, i want a box at the top with username and a dropdown box appears, which then you can tick with the username?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add a header onto the report and in the header add a text box.  When you click into the expression of the text box and filter for parameters, you should be able to add any parameters you want to see on the report.

This will appear on all pages if in the header.  Parameters can be placed anywhere on the report if that is not want you want.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a parameter. Here is an example of how to add a User select parameter:

1. Add a new `Dataset` to populate the parameter selection menu. Your query will be something like `select distinct userid, username from YourTable order by username` I typically name these Datasets something like `DSUserSelect`.
2. On the `Report Data` window, right click `Parameters` and select
   `Add Parameter...`
3. Name your parameter `User`.
4. Under `Available Values`, select `Get values from a query`.
5. Select `DSUserSelect` (or whatever you named the `Dataset` in step 1) for the `Dataset`, `userid` for the `Value`, and `username` for the `Label`.
6. Update your Main `Dataset` query to include `userid = @User` in the `Where` clause. If your dataset is a stored procedure, you will need to add `@User` as a parameter to that stored procedure.

Let me know if I can provide any more detail.